# Difficulty in displaying text in Force layout ? (D3js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using force layout and i have some problem in displaying text in the layout. Here is the screenshot :[image]

and my code is :

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("fill", "blue")
        .attr("r", 4.5)
        .attr("dx", ".10em")
        .attr("dy", ".10em")
        .text(function(d){ return d.name});
```

The text is there in the code, but its not showing in the browser. I even changed the color but nothing helps.

Comment: `circle`s don't support `.text()`. If you want to label nodes, see [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642).

Answer (score 1):

As @Lars Kotthoff mentioned `circle`s don't support `text()`. you should change your code to sample like this:

```
 svg.selectAll("circle")
     .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("fill", "blue")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .attr("cx", ".10em")
    .attr("cy", ".10em");

 svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("dx", ".10em")
    .attr("dy", ".10em")
    .text(function(d){ return d.name});
```

Jsfiddle code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzjebraeil/nyvqvvrz/).

Comment: And you can do such much more stuff if you want. Like increasing text size when mouseover and so. Look for some ideas here ina real project if you wish http://arda-maps.org/familytree/